# Setting a UIWebViewDelegate programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, static-libraries

I am trying to build a custom control based on a UIWebView and compile it into a library for reuse.  Everything was working just fine when I had the code all together in a single test app but I'm having some trouble setting up a the delegate for the view for a library.  Of note, the sample app used interface builder and thus the delegate was set via IB.

**NewsView.h:**

```
@interface NewsView : UIWebView {
   NSObject<UIWebViewDelegate> *delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet NSObject<UIWebViewDelegate> *delegate;
```

In the implementation all of my initialization methods call a common method viewInit

**NewsView.m**

```
@implementation NewsView

@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewInit {

    self.delegate = [[NewsViewDelegate alloc] init];
}
```

If the user clicks on one of the headlines in the view I need the delegate to intercept clicks and launch Safari.

**NewsViewDelegate.h**

```
@interface NewsViewDelegate : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate> {
}
```

**NewsViewDelegate.m**

```
// Intercept URL events
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)myWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
    (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"URL Changed");
    // Check to see if this is a click event
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[request URL]            absoluteString]]];
            return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Unfortunately shouldStartLoadWithRequest never gets called and so clicks are not being launched externally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typically a bad idea to subclass `UIWebView`, and the docs specifically advise against it.  I don't know for sure, but my guess is that `UIWebView` is a class cluster.

To get the effect you want, you might try making your NewsView a plain `UIView`, then add the `UIWebView` as a subview.  From there you can set the UIWebView delegate to the NewsViewDelegate without worrying about the subclass.

The best method might be to create a NewsViewController class that loads your NewsView and implements the `UIWebViewDelegate` methods itself and set the NewsView webView delegate to your NewsViewController.

Comment: Thank you Tyson, I will give that change a try and report back.  I appreciate your help.  Is there a link that you could share regarding the advice not to subclass?  I read the overview at http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html and didn't see it (or just have doc fatigue and missed it).

Thanks again!

Comment: Those are the OS X WebView reference, you should look at the iPhone UIWebView reference. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Luckily the iPhone docs always show up first in my searches. Otherwise I'm sure I'd probably do the same thing all the time. :-)

Comment: Like kubi said, it's in the iPhone docs here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html under Subclassing notes in the overview. Matt Gallagher has a good post about subclassing class clusters here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

Comment: I was finally able to work on this again and creating a UIView and containing a UIWebView did work well, thank you for the advice Tyson. 

I did also want to mention I was able to get that subclassed  UIWebView to work by having it also be the UIWebViewDelegate:

@interface NewsView : UIWebView <UIWebViewDelegate>  

Though I'm not sure when/if that would fall apart somewhere else.  The UIView works very well and also lets me keep the delgates in separate file which I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You are *shadowing* the existing `delegate` property of the webview. Try to simply not include the `delegate` property in your subclass. It should be inherited.

Comment: Thanks St3fan, I did try that earlier and then just again but it didn't seem to do the trick.  From the code above I just commented out all the delegate definition / synthesize in the .h & .m but left self.delegate = [[NewsViewDelegate alloc] init]; in the viewInit method but it didn't change the behavior.  

I'm sure that was a problem but something else is wrong as well.  

Thanks again, I really appreciate your taking the time to review and advise.